# How do I get the second printf to appear while doing the scanf?

Tags: c

I'm try to get the last printf to appear while typing with scanf, but I just can't seem to get it. I'm very new, so I'm sorry if this has been asked before.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){
int f;
printf("*************\n"); 
scanf("%d", &f);
printf("*************");
}
```

Comment: The second `printf` won't execute until the `scanf` returns. So you either need a multithreaded program (e.g. using `pthread` functions), or a multi-process program (e.g. using `fork`).

Comment: Why do you want `printf` to be writing to the screen while the user is trying to type?

Comment: You should also put a type specifier in front of  main like `int main()`

Comment: Your second printf line doesn't have a newline in it. Line buffering is the default on most systems, so you won't see that output unless you add one.

Comment: What do you mean by "while typing with scanf", exactly? It may take you a second to type a number, or a minute, or an hour. Suppose it takes 10 seconds. It will take maybe 1 ms to print a line. You want that line to be printed during what part of these 10 seconds exactly? Note the computer is not clairvoyant and it cannot know when you are going to finish.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you *really* want to do is to take user input between two lines of stars like that:

```
*************
42
*************
```

If that is so and your terminal understands ANSI escape sequences it can be achieved that way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("*************\n\n*************\n\033[2A");
    int f;
    scanf("%d", &f);
}
```

---

On Windows it might be needed to set the console mode to `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`:

```
#include <windows.h>

// ...

auto output_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD mode;
GetConsoleMode(output_handle, &mode);
SetConsoleMode(output_handle, mode | ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING);
```

Comment: Note: this only works in terminals that handle ANSI escape sequences. For example, on windoze, you will just see two-lines of asterisks followed by `"?[2A"` (or something similar).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "this only works in terminals that handle ANSI escape sequences." it already says so in my answer. "Windoze" supports them since anniversary update.

Comment: No dings for it. On my windoze -- since the anniversary update -- it still doesn't work. It is also depends on the font used in the windoze terminal. Some do, some don't. I actually have a square-box, where the `'?'` in my original comment is. Your answer is great, but very dependent on the terminal. Literally, fully updated Win10 and I get `"[2A"`. Mixed bag.

Comment: @try using `SetConsoleMode()` like the update to my answer. It should workx in Windoze.

Comment: Oh, I see the difference, I use the Command Prompt for everything, not Powershell. `cmd.exe` doesn't do ANSI -- unless your `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` invoked in Powershell also effects the `cmd.exe` terminal (I'll try that later). Either way, that nugget is worth the uptick `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "nugget" ... you can have cookies, too, if you'd like ...